# LaTeX skipping table numbers when using table and three part table

Tags: tables, floats, threeparttable

Bizarrely, LaTeX is skipping table numbers when I compile my document. It goes from table 2 to table 4. I'm using two table environments and one three part table. When I remove the second table, the numbers look right when I compile the document.

No idea of why this is happening. Minimal example below.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\frenchspacing
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption{First table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{lrllr}
\toprule
Column A & Column B & Column C & Column D & Column E \\
\midrule
Some text & 1 & Some text & Some text & 111 \\
Some text & 1 & Some text & Some text & 111 \\
Some text & 1 & Some text & Some text & 111 \\
Some ytexty & 1 & Some text & Some text & 111 \\
Some text & 1 & Some text & Some text & 1,111 \\
\addlinespace
Some text & 1 & Some text & Some text & 1,111 \\
Some text & 1 & Some text & Some text & 11,111\\
Some text & 1 & Some text & Some text & 1,111\\
Some text & 1 & Some text & Some text & 1,111\\
Some text & 1 & Some text & Some text & 111\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}

\caption{Second table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rD{.}{.}{3.8}D{.}{.}{3.8}}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Column A} & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Column B}\\
\midrule
Some text & 0.11 & 0.1\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
Some text & 0.11 & 0.1\\
 & (0.1; 0.1) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
Some text & 0.11 & 0.11\\
\addlinespace
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
Some text & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
Some text & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
\addlinespace
Some text & 0.1 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.1)\\
Some text & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.1; 0.11)\\
Some text & 0.11 & 0.11\\
\addlinespace
 & (0.1; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
Some text & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.1)\\
Some text & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item Long table notes.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item First long table notes
\end{TableNotes}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{rD{.}{.}{4.8}D{.}{.}{4.8}D{.}{.}{4.8}D{.}{.}{4.8}}
\caption{Third table}\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Some text} & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Some text} \\
\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-3} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){4-5}
  & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Column A.1} & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Column A.2} & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Column B.1}  & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Column B.2} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Third table \textit{(continued)}}\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Column A} & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Column B} \\
\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-3} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){4-5}
  & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Column A.1} & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Column A.2} & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Column B.1}  & \multicolumn{1}{X}{Column B.2} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule \multicolumn{5}{r}{\itshape continues on next page} \\
\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot
111 & 0.11 & 0.11 &  & \\
 & (0.1; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) &  & \\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.11 &  & \\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.1) &  & \\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.11 &  & \\
\addlinespace
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.1; 0.11) &  & \\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.11 &  & \\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) &  & \\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.11 &  & \\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) &  & \\
\addlinespace
1111 & 0.11 & 0.11 &  & \\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) &  & \\
1111 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.1) & (0.1; 0.11)\\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.1\\
\addlinespace
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.1) & (0.1; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
1111 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.1) & (0.11; 0.1) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.1; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.1) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
\addlinespace
1111 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11\\
\addlinespace
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.1\\
 & (0.11; 0.1) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.1; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
\addlinespace
1111 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.1 & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.1)\\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11\\
\addlinespace
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
11111 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.1; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
1111 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11 & 0.11\\
 & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11) & (0.11; 0.11)\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX output]

Comment: ltablex defines the tabularx environment to be a longtable, with a built in caption.  Either do not use it, or add `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` after using it as a normal tabularx.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you. Do you want to enter this as an answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: It's not so much an answer as a temporary bug fix.

Comment: Yet it's the solution possible with the current version of ltablex. Regardless, it solved my problem, so thank you.